# reg ex works differently on two different files of code

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, match, use-effect

I am using a regEx expression to filter out the youtube ID of a youtube link. I am using it in two different spots - It works great in the first spot... but the second time I use the same expresion, with the same input, it does not work. Here are the two functions.

First - Here is the one that works. The user inputs the data in a text input, and it returns match[2], which is the youtube ID at the end of the link. The user can copy paste in a whole paragraph of text containing a youtube link, and it still works.

```
const handleAddVideo = async () => {
    if(videoLinkHolder){
        var regExp = /^.*(youtu\.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v=)([^#]*).*/;
        var match = videoLinkHolder.match(regExp);
        if (match && match[2].length === 11) {
            props.addPost(
            {
                type: "video", 
                data: match[2], 
                date: new Date(), 
                postId: uuidv4(), 
                rockOn: []
            })
            props.addYoutube(match[2]);
            props.addToSideBar(match[2]);

            //Returns the youtube ID
            console.log(match[2])


            if(props.fbData){
                //post to fb
                try {
                    const postText = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${props.fbData.pageId}/feed?&link=${videoLinkHolder}/&access_token=${props.fbData.pageAccessTokenLong}`, {
                        method: 'POST'
                    })
                    const postTextResponse = await postText.json()
                    console.log(postTextResponse)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('videoLinkInput').value = ''
        } else {
            alert('Sorry! Please use a valid Youtube URL.')
        }
    }else {
        alert('Copy and Paste a Youtube Link Before Submitting!')
    }
}
```

So... Here is my second function. The post comes in from facebook. The object that I receive contains the youtube link.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if(videoLinkHolder.includes('youtu')){
        console.log(videoLinkHolder)
        //Returns the same paragraph of text I enter on the first function. I can see the youtube link in the console. 
        var regExp = /^.*(youtu\.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v=)([^#]*).*/;
        var match = videoLinkHolder.match(regExp);
        console.log(match[2])
        //Returns null

        if (match && match[2].length === 11) {
            setYoutube(match[2])
            console.log(match[2])
        }
    }
}, [videoLinkHolder])
```

Again.. I have used exactly the same inputs into both these functions yet the second one still returns null. Can you help?

Comment: What are the inputs ?

Comment: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) may be of use to you.

Comment: Five Sounds for the V chord! 
https://youtu.be/E48ZR_tHgc8   -- Regardless if the link is alone, or with the extra text, the first function works but the second does not.

Comment: Your code when pasted into the console works fine. Try switching all `var` to `let`, because `var` can lead to some unexpected behavior sometimes

Comment: Got it! -- The string returned from the API for the second function had a \n right before the link causing it not to recognize the link. I did videoLinkHolder.split('\n').join('') and it solved the issue - Not sure if it was the best way?